# How do you set SSE-S3 or SSE-KMS encryption on S3 buckets using Cloud Formation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use a CloudFormation Template to spin up an S3 Bucket in AWS.  One of the requirements for this project is that the bucket be encrypted in place.  I've been trying to find a way to set that up via CloudFormation Template (I've read all the documentation I can get my hands on for SSE-S3, KMS, CFT and S3s...).  But all signs seem to point to it only being available via the console.

I'm worried I'm just missing something obvious and I wondered if anyone knew how I could use CloudFormation Template(or at least something automated) to set the default encryption of an S3 Bucket to SSE-S3 or SSE-KMS?

Comment: You can create a custom resource that will use AWS SDK (like boto3) to set the default encryption configuration on your bucket.

Comment: Here is an example CloudFormation template that assigns a bucket encryption policy https://github.com/dcoker/cloudformation-examples/blob/master/examples/s3/s3-encrypted-only-bucket.json

Comment: This probably doesn't help, but Terraform does support it , https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#sse_algorithm

Answer (score 57, accepted):

AWS added this feature [on January 24th, 2018](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html):

> Use the BucketEncryption property to specify default encryption for a bucket using server-side encryption with Amazon S3-managed keys SSE-S3 or AWS KMS-managed Keys (SSE-KMS) bucket.

JSON

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyBucket": {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "BucketEncryption": {
          "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": [
            {
              "ServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                "SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

YAML

```
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties: 
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-bucketencryption.html

Answer (score 14):

If you have a specific KMS key use the following

```
  ConfigBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: "mytestbucketwithkmsencryptionkey"
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
            KMSMasterKeyID: "YOUR KMS KEY ARN"
```

Comment: Can you update this to show how to generate the KMSMasterKey, and then require that key only for the bucket.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ForceEncryption` option as well:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Amazon S3 Bucket with 

Resources:
  CodeFlexS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Join ["-", ["codeflex-example", Ref: "AWS::Region"]]

  ForceEncryption:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref CodeFlexS3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2008-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
            Resource:
              - !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref CodeFlexS3Bucket, "/*"]]
            Condition:
              StringNotEquals:
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption":
                  - "aws:kms"
    DependsOn: CodeFlexS3Bucket
```

Taken from here: [Creating S3 Bucket with KMS Encryption via CloudFormation](https://codeflex.co/s3-bucket-with-kms-encryption-via-cloudformation/)